# GPU crashes on Yosemite

Tags: macos, crash, gpu

I have a mid-2012 MacBook Pro and updated to OS X Yosemite a few weeks ago. Several times since then the GPU has crashed where I can still move the mouse cursor around the screen and listen to audio but everything else on the screen is unresponsive. I've only managed to remedy this by rebooting the machine.

Is there any way to prevent this happening?

The error logs have multiple instances similar to this:

```
31/10/2014 7:34:45.000 pm kernel[0]: 0000 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000000 
31/10/2014 7:34:45.000 pm kernel[0]: 0x00012540  :  0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00100000 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000000 
31/10/2014 7:34:45.000 pm kernel[0]: 0x00012560  :  0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000000 
31/10/2014 7:34:45.000 pm kernel[0]: 0x00012580  :  0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000000 
31/10/2014 7:34:45.000 pm kernel[0]: 0x000125a0  :  0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000000 
31/10/2014 7:34:45.000 pm kernel[0]: 0x000125c0  :  0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000000 
31/10/2014 7:34:45.000 pm kernel[0]: 0x000125e0  :  0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000000 
31/10/2014 7:34:45.000 pm kernel[0]: 0x00012600  :  0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000000 
31/10/2014 7:34:45.000 pm kernel[0]: 0x00012620  :  0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000000 
31/10/2014 7:34:45.000 pm kernel[0]: 0x00012640  :  0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00100000 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000000 
31/10/2014 7:34:45.000 pm kernel[0]: 0x00012660  :  0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000000 
31/10/2014 7:34:45.000 pm kernel[0]: 0x00012680  :  0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000000 
31/10/2014 7:34:45.000 pm kernel[0]: 0x000126a0  :  0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000000 
31/10/2014 7:34:45.000 pm kernel[0]: 0x000126c0  :  0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000000 
31/10/2014 7:34:45.000 pm kernel[0]: 0x000126e0  :  0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000000 
31/10/2014 7:34:45.000 pm kernel[0]: 0x00012700  :  0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000000 
31/10/2014 7:34:45.000 pm kernel[0]: 0x00012720  :  0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000000 
31/10/2014 7:34:45.000 pm kernel[0]: 0x00012740  :  0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00100000 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000000 
31/10/2014 7:34:45.000 pm kernel[0]: 0x00012760  :  0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000000 
31/10/2014 7:34:45.000 pm kernel[0]: 0x00012780  :  0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000000 
31/10/2014 7:34:45.000 pm kernel[0]: 0x000127a0  :  0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000000 
31/10/2014 7:34:45.000 pm kernel[0]: 0x000127c0  :  0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000000 
31/10/2014 7:34:45.000 pm kernel[0]: 0x000127e0  :  0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000000 
31/10/2014 7:34:45.000 pm kernel[0]: OTHER MMIO Registers
31/10/2014 7:34:45.000 pm kernel[0]: -------------------------------------------------
31/10/2014 7:34:45.000 pm kernel[0]: SYSCONFIG_DFSM                      : 0x00000000
31/10/2014 7:34:45.000 pm kernel[0]: SYSCONFIG_DSSM                      : 0x00000000
31/10/2014 7:34:45.000 pm kernel[0]: SYSCONFIG_DPFC_CONTROL_SA           : 0x00000000
31/10/2014 7:34:45.000 pm kernel[0]: SYSCONFIG_DPFC_CPU_FENCE_OFFSET     : 0x00000000
31/10/2014 7:34:45.000 pm kernel[0]: SYSCONFIG_TILECTL                   : 0x00000000
31/10/2014 7:34:45.000 pm kernel[0]: SYSCONFIG_MISC0                     : 0x00000000
31/10/2014 7:34:45.000 pm kernel[0]: SYSCONFIG_MGGC                      : 0x00000000
31/10/2014 7:34:45.000 pm kernel[0]: SYSCONFIG_MTOLUD                    : 0x8fa00001
31/10/2014 7:34:45.000 pm kernel[0]: SYSCONFIG_GFX_FLSH_CNTL             : 0x00000209
31/10/2014 7:34:45.000 pm kernel[0]: SYSCONFIG_MTOUUD                    : 0x6f600001
31/10/2014 7:34:45.000 pm kernel[0]: SYSCONFIG_MBDSM                     : 0x8da00001
31/10/2014 7:34:45.000 pm kernel[0]: SYSCONFIG_MBGSM                     : 0x8d800001
31/10/2014 7:34:45.000 pm kernel[0]: SYSCONFIG_GTVTD0                    : 0x00000000
31/10/2014 7:34:45.000 pm kernel[0]: SYSCONFIG_GTVTD1                    : 0x00000000
31/10/2014 7:34:45.000 pm kernel[0]: SYSCONFIG_GTVTD2                    : 0x6c62616e
31/10/2014 7:34:45.000 pm kernel[0]: SYSCONFIG_GTVTD3                    : 0x00000000
31/10/2014 7:34:45.000 pm kernel[0]: SYSCONFIG_GTVTD4                    : 0x00000000
31/10/2014 7:34:45.000 pm kernel[0]: SYSCONFIG_GTVTD5                    : 0x11028088
31/10/2014 7:34:45.000 pm kernel[0]: SYSCONFIG_GTVTD6                    : 0x00026104
31/10/2014 7:34:45.000 pm kernel[0]: SYSCONFIG_GTVTD7                    : 0x73672067
31/10/2014 7:34:45.000 pm kernel[0]: SYSCONFIG_GTVTD8                    : 0xc7000220
31/10/2014 7:34:45.000 pm kernel[0]: SYSCONFIG_GTVTD9                    : 0x6720676e
31/10/2014 7:34:45.000 pm kernel[0]: SYSCONFIG_GTVTD10                   : 0x4f4e2073
31/10/2014 7:34:45.000 pm kernel[0]: SYSCONFIG_GTVTD11                   : 0x03894800
31/10/2014 7:34:45.000 pm kernel[0]: SYSCONFIG_GTVTD12                   : 0xdf8948c0
31/10/2014 7:34:45.000 pm kernel[0]: SYSCONFIG_GTVTD13                   : 0xc0310000
31/10/2014 7:34:45.000 pm kernel[0]: SYSCONFIG_GTVTD14                   : 0x00000000
31/10/2014 7:34:45.000 pm kernel[0]: SYSCONFIG_GTVTD15                   : 0x203d2064
31/10/2014 7:34:45.000 pm kernel[0]: ===========================================================================
31/10/2014 7:34:45.000 pm kernel[0]: End Hang Analysis
31/10/2014 7:34:45.000 pm kernel[0]: ===========================================================================
31/10/2014 7:34:45.000 pm kernel[0]: Trying restart GPU ...
31/10/2014 7:34:45.803 pm DumpGPURestart[1239]: Saved gpuRestart report for kernel to /Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/Kernel_2014-10-31-193445_mymachine.gpuRestart
```

Comment: Well the kernel's comment "trying to restart GPU" seems to indicate something went wrong with it.

Comment: can you look in this report on your system /Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/Kernel_2014-10-31-193445_mymachine.gpuRestart

Comment: It's mainly just the contents of memory and registers etc. when the crash happened - http://pastebin.com/KKxSx0V7

Comment: I had this issue on both a mid-2012 non-retina MBP, and an early-2013 rMBP.

I took the rMBP in to an Apple Store, and they did a logic board replacement under warranty. After that, the same issue continues to occur. Interestingly, I've never heard of the newer (read: Intel Iris-equipped) rMBPs having this issue.

Comment: This may be a bug, I have the same problem with the same Mac.

Answer (score 2):

I also experienced these crashes nearly every other day on my mid 2012 MBP.

This solved it for me:

```
Switch off "Automatic graphics switching" for Battery and Power Adapter
settings. This will increase overall power consumption but for me the
crashes have vanished.
```

Explanation: Mac Book Pros (and other Macs) quite usually come with two different GPUs. A low power and a high power GPU. OSX switches between these GPUs on demand. Since Yosemite this seems to be a problem for some people, because their systems are freezing occasionally. If your system suffers from hangs like described by the original poster, try this workaround until Apple fixes automatic GPU switching.

[image: uncheck Automatic graphics switching]

Comment: Do you mean that the power provided on *economic mode* is unsufficient to maintain the RAM content correctly refreshed on the GPU? Hence prohibiting the *automatic graphic switching* would hide the problem.

Comment: @danielAzuelos, All MacBook Pro 15 inch models save the lower-end Iris equipped models can make use of both the integrated Intel graphics and a discrete (usually ATI Radeon but not always) graphics card. The problem is the Macs posses the ability to dynamically switch between graphics sets to preserve battery life/provide improved graphics processing. We are seeing the results of this gone wrong here.

Comment: @danielAzuelos I don't know what causes the problems while switching GPU cores. But I do know that for the "Trying to restart GPU" problems this is indeed a working FIX.

Comment: This solution helped me a lot as I was having the same issue and this change completly fixed it. Also the good news is that now with El Capitan the option can be re-activated and the crashing no longer occurs.

Comment: @Martin The crash still exists in El Capitan ?

Comment: @itsafire no more crashes with El Capitan and the option "Automatic Graphics Switching" can be re-enabled

Answer (score 1):

You may qualify for the MacBook Pro Repair Extension Program. See this for more information https://www.apple.com/support/macbookpro-videoissues/